# If $a^3+b^3+c^3\equiv{0}\pmod7$ then at least one of $a,b$ or $c$ is divisible by $7$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, cubics, perfect-powers

> Show that if $a^3+b^3+c^3\equiv{0}\pmod7$ then at least one of $a$, $b$ or $c$ is  divisible by $7$.

Here it seems Fermat's theorem  has no use. We could consider many different cases of remainders of $a,b,c$ modulo $7$ but that's tedious.
Any ideas for a much shorter solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Fermat's theorem $x^6\equiv1\pmod7$ holds for all $x$ coprime to $7$, so $(x^3)^2\equiv1\pmod7$ hence
$$(x^3)^2-1=(x^3-1)(x^3+1)\equiv0\pmod7$$
and hence $x^3\equiv\pm1\pmod{7}$.

Comment: Can we take sqrt from both sides of such equations?

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi Yes, because we know that $\mathbb{Z}_7$ is a field. You can look another way: $7 \mid x^6 - 1 = (x^3-1)(x^3+1)$ and $7$ has to divide one of them.

Comment: @Stefan4024  In general can we deduce that $a^n\equiv{b^n}\pmod{m} \ \Rightarrow\ a\equiv{b}\pmod{m}$??

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi Unfortunately not, not even for prime numbers. We know that $x^6 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, so $5^6 \equiv 2^6 \pmod 7$, but $5 \not \equiv 2 \pmod 7$

Answer (score 2):

You want to prove the statement:

$[a^3+b^3+c^3\equiv0\pmod7]\implies[a\equiv0\pmod7]\vee[b\equiv0\pmod7]\vee[c\equiv0\pmod7]$

Instead, prove the equivalent statement:

$[a\not\equiv0\pmod7]\wedge[b\not\equiv0\pmod7]\wedge[c\not\equiv0\pmod7]\implies[a^3+b^3+c^3\not\equiv0\pmod7]$

---

Now, observe the following:

- $n\equiv1\pmod7 \implies n^3\equiv1^3\equiv  1\equiv1\pmod7$
- $n\equiv2\pmod7 \implies n^3\equiv2^3\equiv  8\equiv1\pmod7$
- $n\equiv3\pmod7 \implies n^3\equiv3^3\equiv 27\equiv6\pmod7$
- $n\equiv4\pmod7 \implies n^3\equiv4^3\equiv 64\equiv1\pmod7$
- $n\equiv5\pmod7 \implies n^3\equiv5^3\equiv125\equiv6\pmod7$
- $n\equiv6\pmod7 \implies n^3\equiv6^3\equiv216\equiv6\pmod7$

Therefore, $[a\not\equiv0\pmod7]\wedge[b\not\equiv0\pmod7]\wedge[c\not\equiv0\pmod7]\implies$ one of the following:

- $a^3+b^3+c^3\equiv1+1+1\equiv 3\equiv3\not\equiv0\pmod7$
- $a^3+b^3+c^3\equiv1+1+6\equiv 8\equiv1\not\equiv0\pmod7$
- $a^3+b^3+c^3\equiv1+6+1\equiv 8\equiv1\not\equiv0\pmod7$
- $a^3+b^3+c^3\equiv1+6+6\equiv13\equiv6\not\equiv0\pmod7$
- $a^3+b^3+c^3\equiv6+1+1\equiv 8\equiv1\not\equiv0\pmod7$
- $a^3+b^3+c^3\equiv6+1+6\equiv13\equiv6\not\equiv0\pmod7$
- $a^3+b^3+c^3\equiv6+6+1\equiv13\equiv6\not\equiv0\pmod7$
- $a^3+b^3+c^3\equiv6+6+6\equiv18\equiv4\not\equiv0\pmod7$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that none of $a,b,c$ is divisible by $7$.

Write $a^3+b^3 \equiv -c^3$, square both sides, and use Fermat:

$ a^6 + 2a^3b^3 + b^6 \equiv c^6 $

$ 1+2a^3b^3 + 1\equiv 1 $

$ (ab)^3 \equiv 3$

But $3$ is not a cube mod $7$.